# Remove text between two occurrences in Word with Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I have a piece of text tagged with `##ABC`, so it looks like this:

```
Some text ##ABCtext to be found##ABC some text
```

I need to find and remove the ##ABCtext to be found##ABC with interop. So far, I've come up wit the following code, which, however, seems to do nothing:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = document.Range();

rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.MatchWildcards = true;
rng.Find.Text = "##ABC(.*?)##ABC";
rng.Find.Replacement.Text = "";

rng.Find.Forward = true;
rng.Find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;

rng.Find.Execute(Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tested the search string in the Word UI to see if it actually finds anything? I don't see any `.` in the sample text... I'd think only a `*` should be in the parentheses?

Comment: Sometimes, the most simple answers are the most helpful. Thank you, Cindy, using the word UI, I've been able to realize that the expression I need is '##ABC*##ABC'. I will self-answer the question in 2 days when SO allows me to do so, or you may do it if you don't mind :-)

Comment: Glad it turned out to be something as simple as that :-) Actually, I'd categorize this as "unreproducible", meaning it's unlikely to be a helpful addition to the Stack Overflow Q&A, so I'm going to vote to close as such.

Comment: All right, agreed.